# Migrating Foxpro database (.DBF) to Sql database using VB.Net

Tags: sql, vb.net, dbf

I am working on application to migrate DBF file data to SQL.
Kindly suggest be how to start with it.

Thanks

Comment: visual foxpro and MS SQL Server ?http://fox.wikis.com/wc.dll?Wiki~UpsizingWizard click here to read this. Includes how to successfully export stored procedures and other modules also. Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 2):

I would use SSIS (Sql Server Integration Services) to map from the old database to a new one. Is it a one time job, or is it a continuous integration?

Answer (score 0):

Use the Sql Server Upsizing Wizard from within FoxPro.

I've done it before, and it does work. It works with Sql Server 2005 and 2008.

Google for "foxpro sql sever upsizing wizard" for plety of info.